# Windows bluetooth headset options disabled

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I have a Skullcandy smoking Buds 2 wireless headset and it seems that the 2 options for enabling music and calls are disabled. I had connected to the same laptop before and was able to use the headset for music and VOIP calls. I have tried many times to restart the PC, disconnect and connect the headset etc, but with no luck.

I have seen other posts where OP is asked to click on the "Listen to Music" link. Please note that in my case these links are disabled.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below, show you was the root cause of this issue, try this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172605

to delete this update:

Control Panel > Programs > Program and Features > Installed Updates, there go to section  Microsoft Windows and when you found windows update number   KB3161608 (use on windows 7), and restart your PC.

Maybe will be need delete and add again your headset device before that come back to work.

I test that and work fine for a couple of unit with windows 7, I hope you can fixed too with this.

Regards

VR.